# Spark calculate number of times a user has tweeted

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have to calculate the number of times a user has tweeted, with data being in a JSON file. I tried `groupByKey` and `reduceByKey` but the output is user id and the tweet itself, not the count of tweets.

Code:

```
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext

sc = SparkContext("local", "Twitter")
sqlc = SQLContext(sc)


df = sqlc.read.json("file.json")
tweets = df.select("user.id","text")
users = tweets.rdd.reduceByKey(lambda x,y:x+y)
```

How do I get the count of tweets by their respective users as key?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually i found a solution to this. Hope this helps someone.

```
users = tweets.rdd.groupByKey().mapValues(len)
```

Answer (score 1):

All you need is:

```
df.groupBy("user.id").count()
```

This:

```
tweets.rdd.reduceByKey(lambda x,y:x+y)
```

just adds second element (probably `str` concatenating results).